# How to replace a text in pdf file with ITextPDF library?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a requirement to replace a placeholder like ${placeholder} with an actual value, but I could not find any working solution... I've ben following by https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/replacing-pdf-objects and it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's not so easy to "replace" the content of a pdf file, since it could have been written in a different way. For example, suppose that you want to replace a chunk "Hello" with a chunk "World". You'd be lucky if "Hello" has been written to a pdf as a whole word. It might have been written as "He" and "llo", or even "o", "l" , "l", "e", "H", and the letters migth be placed in a different parts of the content stream.

However one can remove the content and then place some other content on the same place.

Let's look at how it could be done.

1) I advice you to use iText's `pdfSweep`, since this tool is able to detect the areas on which the content has been placed and remove the content (it's important to mention that pdfSweep doesn't hide content, it removes it completely)

Please look at the next sample: https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfsweep/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/pdfcleanup/BigDocumentAutoCleanUpTest.java

Let's discuss `redactTonySoprano` test. As you can see, one can provide some regexes (for example, ""Tony( |_)Soprano", "Soprano" and "Sopranoes") and iText will redact all the matches of the content.

Then you can just write some text upon these areas using iText either via lowlevel api (PdfCanvas) or via more complex highlevel api (Canvas, etc).

Let's modify the soprano sample I've mentioned before a bit:

2) Let's add some text upon the redacted areas:

```
for (IPdfTextLocation location : strategy.getResultantLocations()) {
PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(location.getPageNumber()+1);
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), page.getDocument());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, location.getRectangle());
canvas.add(new Paragraph("SECURED").setFontSize(8));
```

}

The result is not ideal, but that is just a proof of concept. It's possible to override the extraction strategies and define the font of the redacted content, so that it could be used for the new text to be placed on the redacted area.

Comment: It could help, but there are warnings **13:54:52.660 [main] WARN  c.i.layout.renderer.RootRenderer - Element does not fit current area. ** and nothing replaced... I'm digging into the code

Comment: ... and the matched words are overlaps with black rectangle

Comment: Disable drawing of any colored rectangles on the redacted areas:




        strategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("Tony( |_)Soprano").setRedactionColor(null));
        strategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("Soprano").setRedactionColor(null));
        strategy.add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("Sopranos").setRedactionColor(null));

Comment: Your warnings are logged during addition of the content to `Canvas` object, aren't they? Are you sure that the content you try to place fits the area with which the `Canvas` object has been created?

Comment: the cleanupstrategy is finding all the references on all pages of the pdf, but strategy.getResultantLocations is only returning the location on page 1. How can i get all the locations?

Answer (score 4):

Sample code below for replace content in PDF using iText

```
    File dir = new File("./");
    File [] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".pdf");
        }
    });

    for (File pdffile : files) {
        System.out.println(pdffile.getName());
        PdfReader reader = null;
        reader = new PdfReader(pdffile.toString()); 

      PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
      PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
      if (object instanceof PRStream) {
          PRStream stream = (PRStream)object;
          byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
          String dd = new String(data);
          dd = dd.replace("0 0 0 rg\n()Tj", "0 0 0 rg\n(Plan Advanced Payment)Tj");
          System.out.print(dd);
          stream.setData(dd.getBytes());
      }
      PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
      new FileOutputStream("./output/"+pdffile.getName())); // output PDF
      stamper.close();
      reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: This only works under benign circumstances. Reasons have been explained in many questions on stack overflow. By the way, the OP mentioned that a certain itext example doesn't work for him, and your code essentially corresponds to that example.

Comment: I was able to adapt this to work for me with iText 7 so to anyone else reading this, you may be able to do some simple text replacements with this code.

Comment: @test can you share your code?

Comment: @Patrick https://pastebin.com/EY0f3Dqt - it's in VB.NET